# Quazip too many files

Tags: c++, zip, 64-bit, archive, quazip

I'm having a problem with QuaZip.

I have a program that extracts files from zip archives. The unzip library I was using hadn't been maintained in about 10 years and had problems with the archive contained more than about 65000 files, so I converted my program to use QuaZip.

It turns out that QuaZip has the same problem. I have an archive that 7-Zip shows has 67946 objects. QuaZip only sees 2397 files. ZipInfo also shows only 2397 files. It appears that these tools have not been updated for the newer zip64 format, although QuaZip does seem to use QuaZipFileInfo64 which presumably is there to support the ZIP64 format. Also, Wikipedia documents QuaZip as supporting the new format.

Calling getEntriesCount() for the quazip object returns 2397.
Using the JlCompress::getFileList code to get the list of files only returns 2397.

Not 100 percent sure what I am asking. Does QuaZip support more than 65500 files in an archive? If so, is there a reason why it would be acting as if it doesn't?

Comment: Hmmm, a 16-bit maximum unsigned value is 65535.  Could this be an issue?

Comment: It appears that the unzip library used by QuaZip does use an int64 for storing the number of files.

Comment: Presumably the change made for zip64 was to change all the 16 bit variables to 64 bit.

Comment: I think that there may be problems in the zip archive. ZipInfo does correctly determine that there are 67933 files in the archive but says that the central directory contains 2397 entries. There is only one central directory record. I believe that the original zip library zipped up all of the files, but overflowed the two bytes of the number of entries field in the central directory. unzGoToNextFile in unzip.c assumes that the number of entries is correct.

Comment: Despite this, both zipInfo and 7-Zip does come up with the correct number of files. I guess I need to figure out how they do that.

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected in my last comment, the number of entries field in the central directory header is incorrect having overflowed on the creation. The solution I came up with was to remove the code in unzGoToNextFile that assumes that that entry is correct.